# How to calculate 3 prime numbers in sequence and divide two of them

Tags: c

That is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int min=0, med=0, max=0, n=0, t=2,
        k=2, j=2, flag=0, counter=0,
        a=0, b=0, c=0;
    scanf("%d%d", &min, &max);
    for(; min<=max; min++){
        while(t <= min/2){
            if(min%t==0){
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
            t++;
        }
        if(flag==0){
            counter++;
        }
        t=2;
        flag=0;
    }
    printf("%d", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

This code prints all the prime numbers of a given range.
I want to store the first 3 prime numbers into different variables, and then check if the minimum and the maximum divided by two equals the mid one.

Also, I want to keep doing it until the program reaches the end of the range.

I have no idea how to store the first three in different variables inside the loop, or even if have I cannot do it.
I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: Need more clarification.  Can you give some examples of the input, and expected output.

Comment: @gagarwa if I input 3 and 5, the output would be 1, because the first prime would be 3 and the 3rd one would be 7, 7+3 = 10/2 = 5. The next one following this pattern would be 53, which is 47+59/2.

Comment: You actually don't need to store the three primes. You can simply store the difference, and the last prime seen. For example, instead of storing 3, 5, 7, you would store a difference of 2, and last prime seen was 5. Then when you determine that 7 is a prime, and you see that 7 - 5 is 2, you have a winner.

Comment: @user3386109 I mean, the range could be between 3 and 2001, would it work? thanks for the comment:D

Comment: Yes, it will work. Given `a < b < c`, if `c-b == b-a`, then `(a+c)/2 = b`.

Comment: @user3386109 I'm sorry for being arrogant but I'm a begginer. I am still wondering how could I implement that inside the loop, because it only gives me one value which is "min".

Comment: *"This code prints all the prime numbers of a given range"* Well, no. It only prints *how many* primes there are in that range.

Answer (score 0):

> I am still wondering how could I implement that inside the loop, because it only gives me one value which is "min".

You could store the current found prime in another variable (`c`) after you stored that variable in another variable (`b`) after you stored that variable in another variable (`a`); this way, you have the last seen three primes at hand.

```
            a = b, b = c, c = min;
            if (b-a == c-b) printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
```